# Как поменять цвет неактивной кнопки Qt Creator с++

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Хотел изменить цвет кнопки когда она неактивна но столкнулся с проблемой что она не меняется. Пытался сделать через Qt Creator в настройках палитры, но ничего не вышло. Решил сделать через код создав палитру вручную в конструкторе окна, тот же результат.

Код:

```
Database_add::Database_add(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Database_add)
{
    

    ui->setupUi(this);
    

    QPalette m_pal;
    m_pal.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Button, QColor(240, 75, 78));
    ui->imageButton->setPalette(m_pal);
    ui->imageButton->setEnabled(false);

}
```

В итоге кнопка остаётся серой, цвет не изменился:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать в данной ситуации?

Comment: смотрите `QWidget::setStyleSheet(const QString &styleSheet)`

Comment: @PavelGridin что конкретно там смотреть? В StyleSheet как я понял невозможно задать параметры для выключенного виджета

Comment: там есть ссылка на `Qt Style Sheets` и далее по ходу изучения можно попасть на `Qt Style Sheets Reference` и `Customizing QPushButton`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139616/how-to-set-a-different-background-color-to-a-disabled-button-with-qss

Comment: это кстати не обязательно делать из кода, можно из дизайнера правой кнопкой на виджет и `Change styleSheets...`